# How do I lock items and folders in place in SAP Easy Access Menu?

Tags: sap

For a specific user, I want to disable all customization options of SAP Easy Access Menu. Moving transactions and folders to a different location, moving them into other folders, etc.

I want the SAP menu to be completely static and not able to be modified.

Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Users can't edit neither SAP menu not user menu. Only favorites

Comment: If that's the case, can I prevent them from moving around their favorites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to restrict user from creating favorites or lock them. I checked some standard code and found no single point where permissions are checked during this operation.

You can only completely disable certain type of menu for user, for that one should create entry in table `USERS_SSM`, the fields are rather self-explanatory:

[image]

The favorite items themselves are stored in table `SMEN_BUFFC`. Theoretically you can lock this table for CRUD and thus prevent users from updating favorites. However, I do not know safe and stable way to do this in SAP, and locking system table can lead to dramatic consequences.